# NancyFX: How to persist a Dictionary

Tags: c#, rest, dictionary, nancy

I want to have a dictionary that I can add/remove entries to it

I saw this answer here but it didn't work for me

[NancyFX: How to use bootstrapper to persist an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360280/nancyfx-how-to-use-bootstrapper-to-persist-an-object)
But I cannot preserve entries in the dictionary

Is there a way that I can make it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way
by just setting my dictionary to static or in a static class
In this way I will always access it and add entries to it and preserve my entries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DI framework used by Nancy to specify dependencies for modules. `AsSingleton()` helps you to have one instance for all modules.

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer    container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register<IMyDictionary, Dictionary<string,string>>().AsSingleton();
    }
}
```

And include this

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
   public HomeModule(IMyDictionary dict)
   {
     Get["/"] => dict;
   }
```

}